# Ajax call overwrites $(this) object in widget factory

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Widget Code :

```
    (function($){

        $.widget("demo.widget", {

            _create: function() {
            },

            _init: function() {
            },

            load: function(){
                var widget = this;
                $.post(
                    Url, 
                    ajaxUtils.success(function(json) {
                    //variable widget is overwritten here if I create multiple instances of the widget

                    alert(widget.element.data("name"));
                    }), "json");

            },

            setOptions: function(name) {
                $(this).data("name", name);
            }

    })(jQuery);
```

I create Multiple instances of the same widget.

```
    $('<div/>').widget();
    $('<div/>').data('widget').setOptions("Name1");
    $('<div/>').data('widget').load();

    $('<div/>').widget();
    $('<div/>').data('widget').setOptions("Name2");
    $('<div/>').data('widget').load();
```

But the widget variable in the ajax success call always returns Name2. How should I write the code to store instance specific data?

Comment: What's going on in this code?  Where is `$.fn.widget` set (`$.widget` is *not* the same)?  Each call to `$('<div/>')` makes a *new* div element.  What is `ajaxUtils.success`?  What is `$.widget("demo.widget", ...` doing?  Can you try to explain this a bit more?

Comment: Rocket is correct, first you should do var $div = $('<div />'); and then access by $div.widget() so you are dealing with the same element.

Comment: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory

Comment: @Rocket he's using the jQuery UI widget system. `$.widget("namespace.plugin",obj)` creates a `$.fn.plugin` plugin.

Comment: `this` in the context of `var widget = this` is the plugin object, not the element that the plugin was initialized on. did you mean `widget.element.data("name")`?

Comment: @KevinB: I've never heard of the `$.widget` method, thanks.

Comment: @Esailija: Thanks for the link, I've never heard of that before.

Comment: @KevinB .. That was a typo. I fixed that. It should be widget.element.

Comment: @Rocket Ajaxutils.success is a callback triggered when the ajax call is successful

Comment: @Blacklabel: Does `ajaxUtils.success` return a function?

Comment: It calls the anonymous function given to it. It calls it with the data returned from the server.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the context of `var widget = this` is the plugin object, not the element that the plugin was initialized on.

This:

```
alert(widget.data("name"));
```

should be:

```
alert(widget.element.data("name"));
```

Edit: I don't know what's going on with the `ajaxUtils` object and its success method, is it returning a function that gets called on the `$.post` success?